# Updating OS X to newer version

Tags: macos, software-update

Does updating of OS X operating system updates built-in software like Apache, git, PHP, Ruby ? If it is what happens with old software ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple occasionally provides updates to system binaries. The older versions are replaced by the newer versions. If you wish for more control over the versions used by certain software, you can use a package manager such as Homebrew.